# How to include skins in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I developed a new iPad calculator and am working on an update for it that has a settings option where you can change the app's skin.  Currently, I am using different `UIViewController`s for that, but it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on @MJN's answer, once you have selected a skin/theme class, you can easily apply it across your app using [`UIAppearance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), which lets you set styles for all instances of common `UIKit` classes like `UIButton`, `UIBarButtonItem`, `UINavigationBar`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an `AppSkinProtocol` that has methods like the following

```
- (NSString*)skinIdentifier;
- (UIColor*)highlightedButtonColor;
- (UIImage*)successfulDownloadAlertBackground;
```

Then make subclasses of NSObject that conform to your AppSkinProtocol.

You can then make a `AppSkinManager` to save the selected skin to `NSUserDefaults`. When the app launches load the skin with the identifier matching the string saved to defaults.